# Php form submit not working. What's wrong with it?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, submit

I am simply trying to add form data(email, date) to mysql database. Below is my code.  It looks fine but for some reason, every time I submit the form, it doesn't do anything. I don't get any error messages. The only change I see after submit is this in the browser url search field at the top. "/localhost/?email=&submit=Notify+Me"

The database is connected and the table/column names match correctly.  The form itself simply does not process.  Can you take a look and see if there's anything wrong with it?

```html
                    <?php
     
     if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      
      $email = trim($_POST['email']);
      
      if(empty($_POST['email'])) {
       
       $error = 'Please enter your email address.';
       
      } else {
      
       $newEmail = $email;
       $date   = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   
       $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO email_list(email, date) VALUES(:email, :date)");
       $insert->bindParam(':email', $newEmail);
       $insert->bindParam(':date', $date);
       $insert->execute();
       $result = $insert->execute();
       
       if($result == false) {
       
        $error = 'There seems to be a problem. Please try again.';
       
       } else {
       
        $success = 'Success.';
        
       
       }
      }
     }
     ?> 
     <div id="error"><?php echo $error; ?></div>
     <div id="success"><?php echo $success; ?></div>
     
     <form action="" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter email address"/>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Notify Me"/>
     </form>
```

Comment: mixing post with get .. why 2 forms

Comment: Use the tools http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php - then tell "us".

Comment: You also have 2 forms with the same name attributes; why?

Comment: form says post, but url indicates get, how odd

Comment: @Dagon Good catch ^ - Resulting in *silent failure*.

Comment: `method`... lordie @Dagon why do these always *slither* by us? Type are for inputs, not form, *duh* on me.

Comment: DOHHHHHH, also drop `enctype="multipart/form-data"` your not uploading a file

Comment: The second form is just duplicate mistake on my part.

Comment: Alright so I have updated my original code with fix.

Comment: So, I take it problem solved then....`?`

Comment: Yes the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have method="post" but not type.

This is what you have:

```
<form action="" type="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

This is what you need:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Of course. I knew it was something small that I over looked.  Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

The form is submitting using GET instead of POST because you have type="post" rather than method="post" on the form. Type isn't a valid attribute so id defaults to GET and then is ignored by your script since you are checking for $_POST.

Comment: you missed the boat bro

Comment: Yeah. I saw the notification as I was hitting enter. :)

Comment: @Dagon They were probably busy writing at the same time, and have a lot more text in their answer ;-)

Comment: its why i always fail, i type slow